# Changing content inside html with nodejs without rendering page

Tags: html, node.js, express

Just learning nodejs. I want to change content inside my html without completely rendering in the page when I post.

Here is my current code.

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
var arr = [];

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', {messages: null, error: null});
})

app.post('/user', function (req, res) {
        var input = req.body.userInput;
        var output = "";
        arr.push(input);
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length;i++){
            (function(){
                console.log(arr[i]);
                output +=arr[i] + "</br>";
            })(i);
      }
      res.render('index', {messages: output, error: null});  
})


app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Thanks. Any advice is really appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't understand your question? Do you mean `lazy loading` ?

Comment: Sorry, so I want to dynamically change to messages value without reloading the whole page - as it's doing currently.

Comment: @Buupu You will need to use JavaScript on the frontend to achieve that.

Comment: Instead of rendering a page using `res.render()`, send just the data in json like `res.json({messages: output, error: null})`. Make it a REST API. Then use the json in the front-end to update the page without reloading the full page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send just the data:

```
app.post('/user', function (req, res) {
        var input = req.body.userInput;
        var output = "";
        arr.push(input);
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length;i++){
            (function(){
                console.log(arr[i]);
                output +=arr[i] + "</br>";
            })(i);
      }
      res.status(200).json({messages: output, error: null});//Not rendering new page, just sending data
})
```

In the front-end, handle as follows if you're using plain JS:

```
function handlePostUser() { // Invoke this on form-submit or wherever applicable
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", 'your link/user', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            var payload = { data to post };
            xhr.send(payload);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4 && !xhr.status) {
                    // Handle error
                    console.log("FAILED");
                } else if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                    console.log("SUCCESS");
                    //your logic to update the page. No reloading will happen
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Think I understand better.

Comment: Hi again, I've tried to make the changes, but it seems when I submit the page just changes into the json text. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: How are you invoking the API? If you're giving your URL in `action` attribute of `form` element, then it'll redirect. Instead use event handlers to invoke XHR or AJAX from javascript. Which framework/library are you using in the front-end?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with server-side code.

You could have to write client-side JavaScript to manipulate the DOM of the existing page.

That JS could use Ajax to get fresh data from the server. You could either write client-side code to extract the portion you care about, or create a different server-side endpoint that only returns the bit of data you want.